# Android disable physical buttons

Tags: android

Please excuse my bad English, I'm French ;)

My boss ask me to developp an app which have to be always on the user screen.
I have to disable the three Android native buttons (back, home and history buttons).

How can I do that ?
Create a custom launcher ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you disable those 3 buttons, How do you intend to exit the App?

Comment: It's a system with only one App available, you mustn't intend to exit the app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you can use the immersive mode (only for >= KitKat), but the user can always display these buttons.

The custom launcher app is the solution for you.

Comment: Thanks man. Have you got code sample for the custom launcher home button interception ? ;)

Comment: You will find this very easily with google (you can also take a look at the android launcher source code).

Comment: (I have to catch the event before the onResume call on the custom launcher...)